# React redux notify rematch issue

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, rematch, react-redux-notify

Having trouble rendering Notify (notification component that is triggered onClick) component using rematch: redux framework to build store from models. `dispatch(createNotification(config))` is being trigger but its not updating the state. Any idea why? My guess is the rematch framework not binding notifyReducer correctly. In redux devtools this is what I get:

Action:

```
ADD_NOTIFICATION // action being dispatched
type(pin): "ADD_NOTIFICATION"
notification: 
message(pin): "THIS NOTIFICATION WORKS!"
type(pin): "SUCCESS"
duration(pin): 0
canDismiss(pin): true
icon: { ... }
id(pin): 1537900315811
```

State:

```
Notifications: [] // not being updated when ADD_NOTIFICATIONS triggers
```

#### models/notifications.js

```
import notifyReducer from 'react-redux-notify'

export default {
  state: [],
  reducers: { notifyReducer },
}
```

#### store.js

```
import { init } from '@rematch/core'
import notifications as models from './models'

const store = init({ models })

export default store
```

#### Containers/ExampleComponentContainer.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { createNotification } from 'react-redux-notify'
import ExampleComponent from '../../components/ExampleComponent'
import store from '../../store'

const { dispatch } = store

const mapStateToProps = ({ notifications }) => ({ notifications })

const mapDispatchToProps = ({}) => ({
  createNotification: config => {
    dispatch(createNotification(config))
  },
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(ExampleComponent)
```

#### Components/ExampleComponent

```
import { Notify, NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SUCCESS } from 'react-redux-notify';

class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
  successNotification = {
   message: 'IT WORKS!',
   type: NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SUCCESS,
   duration: 0,
   canDismiss: true,
   icon: <i className="fa fa-check" />
  }
   handleClick = () => {
    const {createNotification} = this.props;
    createNotification(mySuccessNotification);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <Notify />
        <button onClick={this.handleClick()}>Dispatch Notification! 
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```